# How can I capture a word that starts with 1 and ends with 0 in AWK?

Tags: regex, awk

We're given languages, for example `{w | w begins with a 1 and ends with a 0}.` We're asked to generate regular expressions and AWK expressions. For this example I know the regular expression answer would be `1Σ*0`. I'm just wondering how you would generate a similar AWK expression. I thought that AWK was a text processing language so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? Be careful; I think there is a mistake in the regexp you provide in your post.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by REG or AWK.

Comment: @melpomene well REG means regular expression.. Not sure myself about AWK, all i know is it's a langue that you use on the linux command line

Comment: @Baruchel Well I'm basically asking what is an AWK expression and how would i generate one for the example I gave ..and thanks I'll take a look into that

Comment: Seems you missed the last school lesson...

Comment: @melpomene not the example I gave no.

Comment: What programming language/tool includes `Σ` in their regular expression specification? What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

### Use `match()`

Use GNU awk's [match() function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions), like so:

```
$ echo 1234567890 | gawk '{ match($0, /\<1.*0\>/, m); print m[0] }'
1234567890
```

Other awks may behave differently, but should still have a match() function. YMMV.